# MYSQL Select user name and SUM the reviews for them

Tags: mysql, select, join, sum

I need to create a sql that contains a list of users, and for each user the number they have
reviewed.

I tried this, but it didnt give the desired output because i didnt know how to work the SUM into it.

```
SELECT review.revID, reviewer.name FROM review , reviewer WHERE review.revID = reviewer.revID
```

Any assistance would be apprectiated

here are my tables

```
        CREATE TABLE reviewer (
          revID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
          name VARCHAR(40),
          email VARCHAR(40),
          password VARCHAR(125)
         );

       CREATE TABLE movie (
         movID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
         title VARCHAR(30),
         release_date date
         ); 


        CREATE TABLE review (
          revID INT,
          movID INT,
          rating INT CHECK (rating > 0 AND rating < 10) ,
          review_date datetime(6),
          comment VARCHAR (300),
          helpful INT,
          PRIMARY KEY (revID,movID),

          FOREIGN KEY (revID)
             REFERENCES reviewer(revID),
          FOREIGN KEY (movID)
             REFERENCES movie(movID)
          );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT
count(movId) AS Total_Movie_Count,
r.name AS Reviewer_Name,
r.revId as Reviewer_Id
FROM review
INNER JOIN reviewer r on r.revId = review.revId
GROUP BY review.revId
```

You have to use `GROUP BY` for aggregated column `movId`. And to get the reviewer name, you have to `INNER JOIN` with `revId`.

Answer (score 0):

Select count(*) as no, revId from review
Group by revId

You can use the above query

Comment: Is there a way to display reviewer.name in the result?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use explicit join syntax (e.g. inner join, left join, cross join). Because the relationships among different tables are better explained using explicit join syntax.

```
SELECT    
 review.revID,
 reviewer.name,
SUM(rating) As totalReview    
FROM review     
INNER JOIN reviewer ON review.revID = reviewer.revID    
GROUP BY reviewer.revID;
```

**Note:** You need to use GROUP BY revID in order to get output for each reviewer.

And using aggregate function `SUM` along with group by will provide total rating / review for each reviewer.

*Btw, MYSQL doesn't support `CHECK` constraint.*